# Difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships

Tags: relational-database, relationship

I have to figure out whether the relation shown here is identifying or non-identifying
I am somewhat confused about these two terms. What I understand is given two tables
They have an identifying relationship if a row in one of them uniquely identifies a row 
in another otherwise the relation is non-identifying.
By this logic given an row in Employee table there may not be any assignment
for it in the Job Assignment table. But if I look in the opposite way given any row 
in Job Assignment. There will definitely be a row in Employee table.

I think which way you look is probably not important.
So this relation is identifying. I am not sure if my thought process is correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuFIi.png)

Comment: https://erwin.com/bookshelf/public_html/2020R1/Content/User%20Guides/erwin%20Help/Identifying_Relationships_in_a_Logical_Model.html#:~:text=An%20identifying%20relationship%20is%20a,and%20cannot%20exist%20without%20it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can a 'Job Assignment' exist without being identified with an 'Employee'?

I'm assuming not (your diagram has the crow's foot at the 'Job Assignment' side, `EmployeeId` FK).

The critical aspect is existence: can a book exist without being on a bookshelf? Yes. Can a bookshelf exist without holding any books? Yes. A bookshelf can hold many books, which books it is holding can vary from time to time. So that's not an identifying relationship.

Can an Employee exist without being assigned any Jobs? Yes, I guess.